# How to manipulate a multi-line string in luatex?

Tags: luatex, lua

I want to write a Lua function that processes some multi-line string.

Thus, I created a new file `test.lua` which contains

```
userdata = userdata or {}
function userdata.surroundwithdashes(str)
  str = str:gsub("\n", " (linebreak)\\\\ ")
  tex.print("--" .. str .. "--")
end
```

and added `\directlua{dofile('test.lua')}` to my latex preamble. To call that function, I created a macro `\newcommand{\dash}[1]{\directlua{userdata.surroundwithdashes([[#1]])}}`.

This works well for regular text like

```
\dash{This is some test text}
```

However, It does not recognize line breaks

```
\dash{This is some test text
      with more than one line}
```

And throws errors (undefined control sequence) if I insert them manually

```
\dash{This is some test text \\
      with more than one line}
```

Also, this produces an additional "m" after the "TeX" for

```
\dash{This is some \TeX text}
```

How can I parse the input string reliably and detect newlines in it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the concern is with potential line breaks in a string: Do you want to eliminate them, do you want to preserve them, or something entirely different? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico I want to know where they are in order to interpret the input string correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\\` gets expanded *before* it is passed to the Lua function `userdata.surroundwithbraces`. Because the expansion is an expansion like `\edef` and not LaTeX's `\protected@edef`, macro `\\` breaks.

Expansion can be prevented by e-TeX's `\detokenize`.

Also I prefer `\luaescapestring` (or LuaLaTeX's `\luatexluaescapestring`) for passing string arguments, because the primitive takes care of the necessary escapings:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dash.lua}
userdata = userdata or {}
function userdata.surroundwithdashes(str)  
  str = str:gsub("\n", " (linebreak)\\\\ ")
  tex.print("--" .. str .. "--")
end
\end{filecontents*}
\directlua{dofile('dash.lua')}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\dash}[1]{%
  \directlua{userdata.surroundwithdashes(%
    "\luatexluaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}")}%
}

\begin{document}
  \dash{This is some test text}

  \dash{This is some test text \\
    with more than one line}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

except within verbatim or obeylines etc end of line is reported to the macro layer as a space (or as `\par` if a blank line) so the macro `\dash` has an argument with a single space token between `text` and `with`