# LuaTeX: How to handle a Lua function that prints TeX macros

Tags: macros, luatex, lua

Let's say that I have a Lua function that prints TeX macros: How can those macros be executed during compilation with LuaLaTeX?

In the following example, I defined a LaTeX macro that should print a table (complete with the `tabular` environment and the actual body) through multiple `tex.print` calls:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \directlua{
    tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{lll}")
    tex.print("1 & a & Test A \\\\")
    tex.print("2 & b & Test B \\\\")
    tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
  }
}

\begin{document}
\mytable
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work. Can this be made to work or is this not the way to go at all?

*Note*: Actually, I define a Lua function in a `myfunc.lua` file, then I load it with `\directlua{dofile("myfunc.lua")}` and then I “pass” it to the LaTeX macro.

Related questions:

1. [How to do a 'printline' in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53051/how-to-do-a-printline-in-luatex)
2. [How to manipulate a multi-line string in luatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184963/how-to-manipulate-a-multi-line-string-in-luatex)
3. [luatex and starting TeX macros which handle new line characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198674/luatex-and-starting-tex-macros-which-handle-new-line-characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using the primitive form you need to remember that like `\write` macros are expanded while sending *to* lua so you need

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \directlua{
    tex.print("\string\\begin{tabular}{lll}")
    tex.print("1 & a & Test A \string\\\string\\")
    tex.print("2 & b & Test B \string\\\string\\")
    tex.print("\string\\end{tabular}")
  }
}

\begin{document}
\mytable
\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically I have to write `\string` before _every_ macro called in the `tex.print` statements, is that right?

Comment: @PierPaolo or (simpler) set the `\catcode` of `\ ` to 12 so the argument is written verbatim, the `luacode` package has several wrappers to make it easy to control the different syntax conventions when going from tex to lua or lua to tex