# Perform and show arithmetic with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, calculations

The function I'm trying to create is one that takes two numbers and prints the result with some math. The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    \directlua{
        function prod(a,b)
            tex.print(a "$\times$" b "$=$" a*c)
        end
    }

    The product of 2 and 3: \directlua{prod(2,3)}.
\end{document}
```

I can't make it print the whole statement correctly. How to solve it?

Comment: Try `tex.print("$" .. a .. "\string\\times" .. b .. "=" ..  a*b .. "$")`

Comment: Unlike TeX, to which everything is (by default) a token to be typeset so you can simply write "hello world" and have those words appear in the typeset output, Lua is a general-purpose programming language in which something like `a b` is a syntax error (assuming `a` and `b` are variables). Here, `tex.print` is a Lua function that takes a single string as input, so you need to give it a single string. (There are other forms of `tex.print` too, that you can read in the LuaTeX manual, but those are probably not what you want.) Lua uses `..` to concatenate strings.

Comment: BTW instead of concatenating different strings with `..`, you can also use `string.format` to build a string, e.g. in a file `test.lua` put `function prod(a,b)
  tex.print(string.format([[$%d \times %d = %d$]], a, b, a*b))
end` and in your file do `\directlua{dofile('test.lua')}` -- here the `[[` instead of `"` is to avoid needing to escape the backslash in `\times`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\directlua{
  function prod(a,b)
    tex.print("$" .. a .. "\string\\times" .. b .. "=" ..  a*b .. "$")
  end
}

\begin{document}    
  The product of 2 and 3: \directlua{prod(2,3)}.
\end{document}
```

[image: The product of 2 and 3: 2 × 3 = 6.]

One tricky thing is getting the backslash escaping game right: [LuaTeX: How to handle a Lua function that prints TeX macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233435/35864). `directlua` expands macros before passing them on to Lua, so `\times` gets messed up. But something like `\string\times`, which should stop that expansion does not quite work as intended because `\t` is a special escape for the tab in Lua. Hence we need to escape the backslash there. In Lua you would have to type `\\times`, but in TeX we need to stop the `\\` from being expanded, so we need `\string\\times`. That is one of the reasons why it is often recommended to use the  `luacode` package or externalise Lua functions into their own `.lua` files and then load them with `dofile` or `require` (see for example [How to do a 'printline' in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53051/35864), a bit on `dofile` and `require` can be found at [LuaLatex: Difference between `dofile` and `require` when loading lua files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464056/35864)).

Another thing is that you need `..` to concatenate strings.

Finally, you probably want the entire expression in math mode and not just certain bits.

Also moved the `\directlua` function definition into the preamble. (Thanks to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) for the suggestion.)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It worked here. Thank you!

Comment: And the explanation was really helpful!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    \directlua{
        function prod(a,b)
            tex.print(a.. "$\string\\times$".. b.. "$=$".. a*b)
        end
    }

    The product of 2 and 3: \directlua{prod(2,3)}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, here's a solution that shows how to (a) write the Lua code to an external file, (b) load the Luacode via a `\directlua{dofile("...")}` directive, and (c) set up a LaTeX "wrapper" macro (called `\showprod` in the example below) whose function (pun intended) is to invoke the Lua function.

Note that with this setup, one can write `\\` rather than `\string\\` to denote a single backslash character. (This is also the case for the `luacode` and `luacode*` environments that are provided by the `luacode` package.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{show_prod.lua}
```

```lua
function show_prod ( a , b )
  tex.sprint ( "$"..a.."\\times"..b.."="..a*b.."$" )
end
```

```tex
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%% Load Lua code from external file and define a LaTeX "wrapper" macro
\directlua{dofile("show_prod.lua")}
\newcommand\showprod[2]{\directlua{show_prod(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}
The product of 2 and 3: \showprod{2}{3}.
\end{document}
```