# React to a Command or a Comment to start the Lua Code

Tags: luatex, longtable, itemize, multicolumn

i asked a question a few weeks ago for some Lua Code, that splits my table cell into two cells, if i type a new line.
Here is the code:

```
\begin{luacode*}
function doline(line)
local splitpoint = string.find(line, "=")
local title = line:sub(1, splitpoint-1)
local description = string.gsub(line:sub(splitpoint + 1), "\\par", "\n")
tex.print(title)
for token in string.gmatch(description, "[^\n]+") do
  tex.print("&\\multicolumn{4}{p{11cm}}{" .. token .. "}\\\\[2pt]")
end
tex.print("\\hline")
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\tabularline}[1]{%
   \directlua{
   doline("\luatexluaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}")
}}
```

My problem now is, that there is an empty line, if there is an itemize inside the cell. it looks weird because there are empty lines, that shouldn't be there.
The idea was to react to a string like a `\newcell` or `%---newcell` but i'm not so good with Lua so i'm looking for some help.
Hope, you have any idea.

Comment: This is the question i aked before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482739/create-a-table-with-luatex

Comment: This doesn't look very efficient and like an [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean).  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The Problem is, if there is an massive amount of text in table cell, latex doesn't make a page break and your text disappears at the bottom of your page. The Table is created by a macro, so the idea was to write a code, which writes the Text into a new cell so there is a page break and the text doesn't disappear. but instead of typing a new line in the code i want to do it with a command now, if it is possible

Comment: If you are willing to switch to ConTeXt for that document you can use the `tabulate` environment which can break cells across pages.

Comment: Already tried but the complex tables in ConTeXt have the same problem.

Comment: you really should provide an example document, it is very hard to see how you intend this to be used, in particular you are redefining the standard `\tabularnewline` command to take an argument?? that is likely to break many things and it might be better to use a new command name. Also it seems very odd to want to insert a tex command in the source and then find it in Lua and generate new tex markup rather than simply defining the tex command to do what you want, and not use Lua.

Comment: surely if you want to allow page breaking over a table cell you want to break at lines in the _output_ not based on newlines on the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem now by my own with a workaround.

Comment: In the current state this answer is not an answer, so it is [likely to be deleted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/171701). Please make it become an answer by explaining what you have done to solve the problem, and of course, providing an example code which solves the issue.

Comment: Please consider telling us what that workaround was. Few things are more frustrating for people with a similar problem than finding a question on some forum, only little response and then a "I found a workaround" without a mention of the actual workaround: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Its hard to explain, because i use the Lua-Code in Combination with a macro in LaTeX. The Problem was, there was a big gap between two diffrent itemize elements. First I thought i could fix it by changing the Lua code but eliminated the gap with a negativ \vspace and the option [nosep] from the package enumitem.